# ora-00936 missing expes

Tags: sql, oracle

i can't find what's wrong in this code.

```
UPDATE order_items o
set (DISCOUNT_AMOUNT) =
select T.maxdiscount
from (select customer_id , o.order_id as order_id, D.product_id as product_id, D.total, E.maxdiscount as maxdiscount
from orders o, (select sum(quantity)as total, order_id, product_id
from order_items
group by order_id, product_id)  D,
(select max(discount_amount)  as maxdiscount, product_id
from order_items
group by product_id) E
where o.order_id  = D.order_id and E.product_id = D.product_id) T
where exists T.order_id = o.order_id and T.product_id = o.product_id;
```

the message i get is:

> 936. 00000 -  "missing expression"

no idea what's the problem. thanks in advance!

Comment: Put parentheses around the select.

Comment: `where exists T.order_id = o.order_id and T.product_id = o.product_id;` is wrong. `exists` requires a sub-select, not a condition (plus what jarlh wrote) - and the parentheses around `(DISCOUNT_AMOUNT)` are completely useless.

Comment: i tried, this is not the problem

Comment: thanks horse, the exists was completely not in place.

Answer (score 0):

```
   UPDATE order_items o
   SET DISCOUNT_AMOUNT =
          (SELECT T.maxdiscount
             FROM (SELECT customer_id,
                          o.order_id AS order_id,
                          D.product_id AS product_id,
                          D.total,
                          E.maxdiscount AS maxdiscount
                     FROM orders o,
                          (  SELECT SUM (quantity) AS total,
                                    order_id,
                                    product_id
                               FROM order_items
                           GROUP BY order_id, product_id) D,
                          (  SELECT MAX (discount_amount) AS maxdiscount,
                                    product_id
                               FROM order_items
                           GROUP BY product_id) E
                    WHERE     o.order_id = D.order_id
                          AND E.product_id = D.product_id) T
            WHERE T.order_id = o.order_id AND T.product_id = o.product_id);
```